# Surround Sound on Ubuntu 14.04 with Logitech G430?

Tags: sound, logitech

I have a Logitech G430 headset, that comes with 7.1 surround sound.
On Windows 7, I have the Logitech Gaming Software installed, which allows me to have surround sound on my headset.
I was wondering whether there was a Ubuntu method to allow me to get surround sound on my headset, becuase the methods I have tried haven't worked =(

Any tips?

Answer (score 8):

This site helped me out with that same question. I'm using the Logitech G930 headset.
 Edit the PulseAudio daemon.conf file by opening a terminal and enter:

`gksu gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

And search for: default-sample-channels. Remove ";" from the begining of the line, and instead of "= 2", change it to the number of speakers your system has. For instance if you have a 5.1 system, the number should be 6, **for a 7.1 system: 8** and so on.
This is how that line used to look before you made any changes:

; default-sample-channels = 2

And this is how it's supposed to look after:

default-sample-channels = 8

2. Now you can save the changes and either restart your computer or:

`killall pulseaudio && pulseaudio`

3. Check to see if the channels are muted. Open a terminal and type

`alsamixer`

[image: alsamixer]

4. You can now test the channels by typing this in a terminal:

speaker-test -c 8

Again, replace the number with your number of speakers.

source: http://www.webupd8.org/2009/06/enable-surround-sound-in-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: I did the default-sample-channels thing, however it doesn't make a difference in alsamixer (still same headphone/mic options only)
The speaker test played through all of the headphones' speakers - some where rather quiet, although this was probably normal.

Comment: @user295214 The device will still be on stereo after the mod, but the higher channels will have opened up in the menus. You need to go to pulse or alsa and select the 7.1 channels. Thank you so much Brandma! My ears are so happy. :) +1