# Can't get surround sound working on Logitech G340 Headset [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: drivers, sound, headset

Havn't really tried installing any drivers or anything yet, they worked out of the box except for the 7.1 surround sound. Just wondering if anyone here had any ideas before i start installing drivers that i may not need.

Answer (score 0):

Having the G430 headset I know that the software that Logitech provides is what performs the 7.1 surround sound. Unfortunately this software is only for windows.

I would recommend looking [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491626/surround-sound-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-logitech-g430)